# Keep text within quotation intact, while splitting text

Tags: php, arrays, split, explode, php-7.4

I need the data in the string [$str] that is within quotes to not split.
In this case, "Accounting company" should be kept in one string, not spread.

```
<?php

$str =
'#PROGRAM   "Accounting company"    98.2
 #GENERATED     2020715 "SE"';

$data = explode("\n", $str);

foreach($data as &$value){
    $value = preg_split("/\s+/", $value);
}

var_dump($data);
```

**Result:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "#PROGRAM"
    [1]=>
    string(11) ""Accounting" // Unwanted split
    [2]=>
    string(8) "company""  // Unwanted split
    [3]=>
    string(4) "98.2"
  }
  [1]=>
  &array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(10) "#GENERATED"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "2020715"
    [3]=>
    string(4) ""SE""
  }
}
```

**Wanted result:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "#PROGRAM"
    [1]=>
    string(18) ""Accounting company"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "98.2"
  }
  [1]=>
  &array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(10) "#GENERATED"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "2020715"
    [3]=>
    string(4) ""SE""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a SKIP FAIL pattern to skip matching values from an opening till closing double quote and then match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars to split on

```
"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\h+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jqGTLt/1)

```
$str =
    '#PROGRAM   "Accounting company"    98.2
 #GENERATED     2020715 "SE"';

$data = explode("\n", $str);

foreach($data as &$value){
    $value = preg_split("/\"[^\"]*\"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\h+/", $value);
}

print_r($data);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => #PROGRAM
    [1] => "Accounting company"
    [2] => 98.2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => #GENERATED
    [2] => 2020715
    [3] => "SE"
)
```

If you don't want the empty entry in the second array, you could use the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag:

```
$value = preg_split("/\"[^\"]*\"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\h+/", $value, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/W8mPn)

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution without regex

```
$str =
'#PROGRAM   "Accounting company"    98.2
 #GENERATED     2020715 "SE"';

$quoted = false;
$index = 0;
$data = [];
$rows = explode("\n", $str);

foreach($rows as $row) {
    $temp = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($row); $i++) {
        if ($row[$i] === "\"") $quoted = !$quoted;
        if ($row[$i] === " " && !$quoted) {
            $index++;
            continue;
        }
        
        $temp[$index] = ($temp[$index] ?? "") . $row[$i];
    }
    
    $data[] = array_values($temp);
}

var_dump($data);
```

## Result

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "#PROGRAM"
    [1]=>
    string(20) ""Accounting company""
    [2]=>
    string(4) "98.2"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "#GENERATED"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "2020715"
    [2]=>
    string(4) ""SE""
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/TNAYo)

Still figuring out a regex solution though :)

In case you want to keep the empty element at [1][0]: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/IW0VW)